# How to get Ajax response in TestMethod CUIT

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, coded-ui-tests

I have my test method in a test class. I use Coded UI.
Everything I tested so far seems good. Now I want to await a Ajax call on clicking the Save button, but I don't know how.
Is it possible to do that? And if my Ajax response is above 500ms the test should fail.

This is my sample class:

```
 [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        string serviceName = "xxxxxxx.exe";
        var binPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)));
        string servicePath = @"\ServiceProjects\vvvvvv\bin\Debug\";
        string absolutePath = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", binPath, servicePath, serviceName);

        Process.Start(absolutePath);

        BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "ie";
        BrowserWindow.Launch(baseAddress);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ManagerTestMethod()
    {

        this.UIMap.ManagerTestMethod_MobilePrefix();

    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {

        this.UIMap.TestCleanup();

    }
```

And in this ManagerTestMethod_MobilePrefix() method I click on the save  button:

```
        public void ManagerTestMethod_MobilePrefix()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        HtmlDiv uISljedećizahtjevNoPane = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument.UISljedećizahtjevNoPane;
        HtmlButton uIItemButton = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument.UIItemButton;
        HtmlCustom uIItemCustom = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument1.UIŠifarniciCustom.UIItemCustom;
        HtmlHyperlink uIMobilniprefiksHyperlink = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument1.UICodelistsSubMenuCustom.UIMobilniprefiksHyperlink;
        HtmlDiv uIItemPane = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument2.UIAps_mng_mobilephonepPane.UIItemPane;
        HtmlSpan uIItemPane1 = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument2.UIAps_mng_mobilephonepPane.UIItemPane1;
        HtmlEdit uIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument2.UIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit;
        HtmlEdit uIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit1 = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument2.UIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit1;
        HtmlEdit uIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit2 = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument2.UIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit2;
        HtmlButton uISačuvatiButton = this.UIAddikoAPSInternetExpWindow.UIAddikoAPSDocument2.UISačuvatiButton;
        #endregion

        // Click '+ Sljedeći zahtjev + No' pane
        Mouse.Click(uISljedećizahtjevNoPane, new Point(1651, 234));

        // Click '+ Sljedeći zahtjev + No' pane
        Mouse.Click(uISljedećizahtjevNoPane, new Point(1778, 308));

        // Click '+' button
        Mouse.Click(uIItemButton, new Point(51, 23));

        // Click custom control
        Mouse.Click(uIItemCustom, new Point(48, 30));

        // Click 'Mobilni prefiks' link
        Mouse.Click(uIMobilniprefiksHyperlink, new Point(87, 18));

        // Set flag to allow play back to continue if non-essential actions fail. (For example, if a mouse hover action fails.)
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;

        // Mouse hover  pane at (1, 1)
        Mouse.Hover(uIItemPane, new Point(1, 1));

        // Reset flag to ensure that play back stops if there is an error.
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = false;

        // Click pane
        Mouse.Click(uIItemPane1, new Point(6, 5));

        // Type 'test1' in 'aps.mng.mobilephoneprefix.details.Code' text box
        uIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit.Text = this.ManagerTestMethod_MobilePrefixParams.UIApsmngmobilephonepreEditText;

        // Type '{Tab}' in 'aps.mng.mobilephoneprefix.details.Code' text box
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit, this.ManagerTestMethod_MobilePrefixParams.UIApsmngmobilephonepreEditSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);

        // Type 'test1' in 'aps.mng.mobilephoneprefix.details.CoreCode' text box
        uIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit1.Text = this.ManagerTestMethod_MobilePrefixParams.UIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit1Text;

        // Type '100' in 'aps.mng.mobilephoneprefix.details.Value' text box
        uIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit2.Text = this.ManagerTestMethod_MobilePrefixParams.UIApsmngmobilephonepreEdit2Text;

        // Click 'Sačuvati' button
        Mouse.Click(uISačuvatiButton, new Point(52, 20));
    }
```

The last step is crucial to me: Mouse.Click(uISačuvatiButton, new Point(52, 20)); in that step I am doing a Ajax call to my API controller in order to insert the data.
I want to be able to catch validations from my form, also I want to be able to catch the response from the Ajax call that is triggered by clicking on the save button.

Answer (score -1):

I may have a idea you could try. I never had a situation like yours, so I can't confirm it will work.

You could provide a hidden control on that form with a value that will only be set if the Ajax call is completed. If you are able to find that control with your Coded UI test, you could run a timer for 500ms after clicking that save button.

Comment: Are you serious? I have 2500 ajax calls, so you suggest me to add 2500 additional fields on each form?

Comment: Please keep in mind you did not provide that information in your question. I answered your specific question. If you did provide that information I would have had a slightly different answer for you. Continuing on that concept with this new information, the hidden control does not have to be on your form. Do these forms share a mutual layout? Adding that control there, you would only be adding it once. You could introduce a counter that way. If the call was successful, the counter adds up 1. You could check if this happened within 500ms.